# Use and save lm summary for multplie lm fitting

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, lm

I work with animal trials in which I try to get information about movement for several groups of animals (normally 4 groups of 12 individuals, but not allways the same).
My final data frame per trial looks like this.

```
> dput(aa)
structure(list(Tiempo = c(618.4, 618.6, 618.8, 619, 619.2, 619.4, 
619.6, 619.8, 620, 620.2, 620.4), UT1 = c(0, 0, 15, 19, 26, 27, 
29, 37, 42, 44, 45), UT2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 18, 19, 21, 21, 
21), UT3 = c(0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 16, 19, 20, 20, 20), UT4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 17, 29, 34, 39), UT5 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), UT6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), UT7 = c(0, 
0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8), UT8 = c(0, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 
33, 80, 119, 122, 130), UT9 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 9, 19, 19, 
19), UT10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 12, 14), TR1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2), TR2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 19, 
32, 37, 43), TR3 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TR4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TR5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 
18, 20, 22, 26), TR6 = c(0, 2, 11, 20, 25, 29, 37, 40, 41, 42, 
43), TR7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TR8 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TR9 = c(0, 0, 4, 9, 16, 19, 23, 27, 
31, 33, 34), TR10 = c(0, 1, 9, 25, 32, 41, 49, 49, 51, 57, 60
), UT1.1 = c(0, 10, 15, 17, 23, 31, 37, 48, 53, 57, 58), UT2.1 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4), UT3.1 = c(0, 2, 11, 14, 20, 22, 
24, 25, 26, 26, 26), UT4.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 13, 13, 
14), UT5.1 = c(0, 3, 5, 7, 18, 19, 19, 27, 37, 39, 42), UT6.1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4), UT7.1 = c(0, 0, 2, 8, 9, 9, 12, 
16, 18, 18, 18), UT8.1 = c(0, 0, 1, 8, 13, 15, 44, 68, 80, 89, 
94), UT9.1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10, 10), UT10.1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), UT11 = c(0, 12, 17, 17, 18, 34, 
74, 116, 131, 145, 170), UT12 = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 14, 21, 
22, 24), TR1.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), TR2.1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 11, 16, 19, 40, 94, 121, 134, 145), TR3.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 
2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7), TR4.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 
4, 5), TR5.1 = c(0, 24, 27, 28, 29, 37, 86, 151, 212, 258, 288
), TR6.1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 9, 12, 12, 13), TR7.1 = c(0, 
4, 7, 28, 47, 70, 108, 125, 127, 127, 127), TR8.1 = c(0, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), TR9.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), TR10.1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 40, 41, 45, 49), TR11 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 4, 8, 10, 11, 17, 23, 25), TR12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Tiempo", "UT1", "UT2", "UT3", "UT4", 
"UT5", "UT6", "UT7", "UT8", "UT9", "UT10", "TR1", "TR2", "TR3", 
"TR4", "TR5", "TR6", "TR7", "TR8", "TR9", "TR10", "UT1.1", "UT2.1", 
"UT3.1", "UT4.1", "UT5.1", "UT6.1", "UT7.1", "UT8.1", "UT9.1", 
"UT10.1", "UT11", "UT12", "TR1.1", "TR2.1", "TR3.1", "TR4.1", 
"TR5.1", "TR6.1", "TR7.1", "TR8.1", "TR9.1", "TR10.1", "TR11", 
"TR12"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to lm the individuals represented in each column using `Tiempo` variable as x so I do it like this:

```
fit<-apply(aa,2,function(x) lm(x~aa$Tiempo))
```

It works perfect but the problem is that all the valuable (and useless) information gets stored in that lm object and I can't extract the data in an efficient way. My lm object looks like this

```
summary(fit)
       Length Class Mode
Tiempo 12     lm    list
UT1    12     lm    list
UT2    12     lm    list
UT3    12     lm    list
UT4    12     lm    list
UT5    12     lm    list
UT6    12     lm    list
UT7    12     lm    list
UT8    12     lm    list
UT9    12     lm    list
UT10   12     lm    list
TR1    12     lm    list
TR2    12     lm    list
TR3    12     lm    list
TR4    12     lm    list
TR5    12     lm    list
TR6    12     lm    list
TR7    12     lm    list
TR8    12     lm    list
TR9    12     lm    list
TR10   12     lm    list
UT1.1  12     lm    list
UT2.1  12     lm    list
UT3.1  12     lm    list
UT4.1  12     lm    list
UT5.1  12     lm    list
UT6.1  12     lm    list
UT7.1  12     lm    list
UT8.1  12     lm    list
UT9.1  12     lm    list
UT10.1 12     lm    list
UT11   12     lm    list
UT12   12     lm    list
TR1.1  12     lm    list
TR2.1  12     lm    list
TR3.1  12     lm    list
TR4.1  12     lm    list
TR5.1  12     lm    list
TR6.1  12     lm    list
TR7.1  12     lm    list
TR8.1  12     lm    list
TR9.1  12     lm    list
TR10.1 12     lm    list
TR11   12     lm    list
TR12   12     lm    list
```

And each animal looks like this

```
 summary(fit$UT1)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ aa$Tiempo)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-6.873 -1.845  1.182  2.314  4.918 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -14642.700   1104.825  -13.25 3.29e-07 ***
aa$Tiempo       23.682      1.784   13.28 3.24e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.742 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9514,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.946 
F-statistic: 176.3 on 1 and 9 DF,  p-value: 3.24e-07
```

I would like to get the summary information organised in a data frame with all animals (or at least the coefficients and R-squared data) in order to keep doing some statistical analysis. Having that information cuould possibly help me to think a function to evaluate if the R-squared is lower than a fixed value and I should check that fit (or discard that animal if it's really not performing well). Besides, I should find a way to make it reproducible because nowadays I'm using

```
FIT<-data.frame(UT1=fit$UT1$coefficients,
              UT2=fit$UT2$coefficients,
              UT3=fit$UT3$coefficients,...)
```

This approach doesn't even meet what I'm trying to do and it's really precarious.
I've made a little search and find about `coef` function but

```
coef(fit)
NULL
```

Comment: instead of `str(aa)` please provide `dput(aa)`

Comment: I would probably just initialize a list of the appropriate length and then simply fit the linear models in a `for` loop. You could pull out the coefficients as you go, or you could extract them later using `lapply`.

Comment: With the code you've already created, you could extract the coefficients into a data frame with `sapply(fit, coef)`.

Comment: @joran I don't have much knowledge about for loops (I know basic stuff, but I don't have much know how to use it in that way) Besides, since I'm planning to change the number of animals I'd have to change it every time or make it adjustable.

Comment: in order to get the coefficients you could just do `fit<-lapply(aa, function(x) coef(lm(x~aa$Tiempo)))`

Comment: @epi10 That worked fantastic! Any idea of how to solve the statistic issue and get more of summary data?

Comment: or R squared in `data.frame` form `fit<-as.data.frame(unlist(lapply(aa, function(x) summary(lm(x~aa$Tiempo))$r.squared)))`

Comment: @David Arenburg Great! I'm going to combine both of your answers using rbind. There's no way I could get this right on my own. Getting this information makes me realise that when animals stay still the fit gives a NaN for R-squared, it should give a 1 but there must be something about how lm is programed. Thanks, I'm thinking of add to your $r.squared something like $error and construct the table little by little. Thanks again, this helped me a lot!

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `fit` list, you can extract the coefficients and r-squared values with

```
fit<-apply(aa,2,function(x) lm(x~aa$Tiempo))
mysummary <- t(sapply(fit, function(x) {
    ss<-summary(x); c(coef(x), 
        r.square=ss$r.squared, adj.r.squared=ss$adj.r.squared)
}))
```

We use `sapply` to go over the list you created and extract the coefficients from the model and the r-squared values from the summary. The output is

```
> mysummary
       (Intercept)   aa$Tiempo  r.square adj.r.squared
Tiempo      0.0000   1.0000000 1.0000000     1.0000000
UT1    -14642.7000  23.6818182 0.9514231     0.9460256
UT2     -8662.4182  14.0000000 0.7973105     0.7747894
UT3     -7535.5091  12.1818182 0.8404400     0.8227111
...
```